# django required=false invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: django, forms, validation

In a django form, I have the error  invalid literal for int() with base 10: " for a field I don't fill. It occurs at the line:

```
if form.is_valid():
```

What I don't understand is that the field has required=False. So if the field is empty, Django should not try to validate it, no?

Here is the model:

```
prelexDosId = models.IntegerField(max_length=7, unique=True, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
```

Here the form:

```
prelexDosId = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^[1-9]([0-9]?){6}$', required=False)
```

Thank you in advance,

Romain

Comment: This looks to me as very complicated boundary `1 <= x <= 9999999`

Comment: Exactly! Is there an easy way to constraint the value?

Comment: `FormField` and `max_value`, `min_value` is the thing you're looking for. However, if you constraints come out from database restrictions, Django comes with `SmallPositiveIntegerField`.

Comment: I used max_value and min_value with IntegerField and it works now! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RegexField` is completely the wrong field to use here. I don't understand why you need to override the default form field anyway, but if you do, you should at least use [`forms.IntegerField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/forms/fields/#integerfield), which takes care of correctly casting the result to an integer on clean.

Comment: It's a modification form, so the user can delete the value! If I don't use regex, what can I use to constraint my field so that the value is between 1 and 9999999 or empty?

Comment: As my link to the documentation shows, `IntegerField` has `max_value` and `min_value` attributes.

Comment: Thanks it worked! I was so stupid to use regex! Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I am just speculating, but perhaps the default value in the model field is causing the problem.

Comment: It has nothing to do with `default` on model field. Empty `RegexField` is `''` that gets passed to model field and casted to `int`, thus the error.